# Extract a hierarchical dataset from a flat set in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to get all the items in a flat dataset that are grouped together to form a hierarchical dataset using Javascript/Node.JS.

I have a solution, but I don't think it's the most elegant and it could probably be improved.

I based my solution of the answer here [Find all objects with matching Ids javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863855/find-all-objects-with-matching-ids-javascript)

My dataset is as follows:

```
let data = [{cid: 1, clbl: 'Rush Shipping', pid:5, plbl: 'FedEx'},
        {cid: 2, clbl: 'Standard Shipping', pid:5, plbl: 'FedEx'},
        {cid: 3, clbl: 'First Class', pid:8, plbl: 'USPS'},
        {cid: 4, clbl: 'Std', pid:9, plbl: 'DHL'},
        {cid: 5, clbl: 'Canada Post', pid:1, plbl: 'Canada Post'},
       ];
```

I would like my output to be something like this:

```
[ { pid: 5,
    plbl: 'FedEx',
    methods: [
       {
         cid: 1,
         clbl: 'Rush Shipping',
       },
       {
         cid: 2,
         clbl: 'Standard Shipping',
       },
   },
   { pid: 8,
    plbl: 'USPS',
    methods: [
       {
         cid: 3,
         clbl: 'First Class',
       },
   },
   { pid: 9,
    plbl: 'DHL',
    methods: [
       {
         cid: 4,
         clbl: 'Std',
       },
   },
   { pid: 1,
    plbl: 'Canada Post',
    methods: [
       {
         cid: 5,
         clbl: 'Canada Post',
       },
   },
 ]
```

I threw together some code that works, but I imagine there has be be a more optimized way to do this and thought I would put it to the SO community.

Here's my solution:

```
var roots = [];

var all = {};
data.forEach(function(item) {
    all[item.pid] = item;
})
Object.keys(all).forEach(function(pid) {
  var items = data.filter(x => x.pid == pid);
  var addItem = {};
    items.forEach(function(item, j) {
    if (j === 0){
        addItem = {pid:item.pid, label:item.plbl, methods:[]};
     }
    addItem.methods.push({cid: item.cid, label: item.clbl});
    });
  roots.push(addItem);
})
console.log(roots);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is more 'optimized' from a memory/speed standpoint but it is a little shorter.

```
let new_data = Object.values(data.reduce(function(o, d) {
    o[d.pid] = o[d.pid] || {pid: d.pid, plbl: d.plbl, methods:[]};
    o[d.pid].methods.push({cid: d.cid, clbl: d.clbl});
    return o;
}, {}));
```

Basically take advantage of the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method in order to build one combined `all` object. Then use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to create an array from the values stored in the `all` object instead of manually pushing them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a way to do this which is harder, not easier.  But it will also involve creating a number of reusable functions.

I'm a big fan of the [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) programming library (disclaimer: I'm one of its authors.)  So when I try to do something like this, I reach for Ramda.  And I find that I can code such transformations in its [REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/) simply by piping together a number of simpler steps.

My pass at this with Ramda looks like:

```js
const transform = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('pid')),
  map(applySpec({
    pid: path([0, 'pid']),
    plbl: path([0, 'plbl']),
    methods: project(['cid', 'clbl'])
  })),
  values
)

let data = [{cid: 1, clbl: 'Rush Shipping', pid:5, plbl: 'FedEx'}, {cid: 2, clbl: 'Standard Shipping', pid:5, plbl: 'FedEx'}, {cid: 3, clbl: 'First Class', pid:8, plbl: 'USPS'}, {cid: 4, clbl: 'Std', pid:9, plbl: 'DHL'}, {cid: 5, clbl: 'Canada Post', pid:1, plbl: 'Canada Post'}];

console.log(transform(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, applySpec, path, project, values} = ramda   </script>
```

All the functions in there are fairly reusable.  So I could start my own little library by including simple versions of each of these functions.  Then this code would be equally simple, and I could use those functions in other places in my application.

Here is another approach, using simplified versions of these functions.  (Note that I rename `map` to `mapObject` here, as any such library I write would contain a simple `map` function that works much like `Array.prototype.map`.  In Ramda, one function covers them both, but that's not as simple to do here.)

```js
// In my utility library
const pipe = (fn1, ...fns) => (...args) =>
  fns.reduce((r, fn) => fn(r), fn1(...args))
const prop = (name) => (obj) => 
  obj[name]
const values = (obj) => 
  Object.values(obj)
const mapObject = (fn) => (obj) => 
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, k) => ({...a, [k]: fn(obj[k])}), {})
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs.reduce((a, x) => ({...a, [fn(x)]: (a[fn(x)] || []).concat(x)}), {})
const applySpec = (s) => (o) =>
  Object.entries(s).reduce((a, [k, fn]) => ({...a, [k]: fn(o)}), {})
const path = (ns) => (obj) =>
  ns.reduce((v, n) => (v[n] || {}), obj)
const project = (ns) => (xs) =>
  xs.map(x => ns.reduce((a, n) => ({...a, [n]: x[n]}), {}))

// In current module
const transform = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('pid')),
  mapObject(applySpec({
    pid: path([0, 'pid']),
    plbl: path([0, 'plbl']),
    methods: project(['cid', 'clbl'])
  })),
  values
)

let data = [{cid: 1, clbl: 'Rush Shipping', pid:5, plbl: 'FedEx'}, {cid: 2, clbl: 'Standard Shipping', pid:5, plbl: 'FedEx'}, {cid: 3, clbl: 'First Class', pid:8, plbl: 'USPS'}, {cid: 4, clbl: 'Std', pid:9, plbl: 'DHL'}, {cid: 5, clbl: 'Canada Post', pid:1, plbl: 'Canada Post'}];

console.log(transform(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<!-- Look, Ma, no Ramda -->
```

All those functions are available [in the Ramda documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/).  Many of them are more sophisticated there, but these simple implementations will take us a long way.