# Filter an object based on another object

Tags: javascript, object

I'd like to transform an object based on a dot notation string in another object. For instance:

```js
const objToTransform = {
  "a": "aValue",
  "b": {
      "c": "cValue",
      "d": "dValue"
  }
};

const filteringObj = {
  "field1": "a",
  "field2": {
    "subfield1": "b.c",
    "subfield2": "b.d"
  }
};

const filteredObj = myFunc(objToTransform, filteringObj);
// expect outputs to be: 
//  {
//   "field1": "aValue",
//   "field2": {
//      "subfield1": "cValue",
//      "subfield2": "dValue"
//    }
//  }
```

I've been working on this seemingly simple thing for hours and I still can't get it to work. I've found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string), which shows you how to get a nested object value with a dot notation string but couldn't get any further sadly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please show how far you did get; you could be just a little bit off, and it would be a shame to waste people's time when it could take 5 minutes, right?

Comment: I just added a function (<10 lines) using lodash that filter recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following steps using recursion:

- Make a copy of the `filteringObj`.
- Create helper function `getByPath` which takes objects and path and return value at that path from nested object
- Create a function `transform` which loops over the keys of `filteringObj`(I named it `pattern` in function)
- In side the loop check if value is an object then call the `transform` function recursively on that subobject
- If its not a object then get the value from the original object `objectToTransform` by using `getByPath` function

```js
const objToTransform = {
  "a": "aValue",
  "b": {
      "c": "cValue",
      "d": "dValue"
  }
};

const filteringObj = {
  "field1": "a",
  "field2": {
    "subfield1": "b.c",
    "subfield2": "b.d"
  }
};

function getByPath(obj, path){
  //console.log(path)
  return path.split('.').reduce((ac,a) => ac[a], obj);
}

function transform(obj, pattern){
  for(let key in pattern){
    if(typeof pattern[key] === "object"){
      transform(obj, pattern[key]);
    }
    else{
      pattern[key] = getByPath(obj, pattern[key]);
    }
  }
}
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filteringObj))
transform(objToTransform, copy);
console.log(copy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create recursive function using `reduce` method that will create recursive call every time when the value is of type object.

```js
const objToTransform = {
  "a": "aValue",
  "b": {
    "c": "cValue",
    "d": "dValue"
  }
};

const filteringObj = {
  "field1": "a",
  "field2": {
    "subfield1": "b.c",
    "subfield2": "b.d"
  }
};

function transform(a, b) {
  return Object.entries(b).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    r[k] = typeof v !== 'object' ?
      v.split('.').reduce((r, e) => r[e], a) :
      transform(a, v)

    return r;
  }, {})
}

const result = transform(objToTransform, filteringObj)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a recursive algo:

```js
const getRefVal=(ePath, eData)=>ePath.split('.').reduce((r,x)=>r[x], eData);

function myFunc(oData, oModel) {
  let ret = {};
  setKeyVal(oModel,ret);

  function setKeyVal(src,res) {              // recursive function
    for (let [k,v] of Object.entries(src)) {
      if (typeof src[k]==='object') { res[k] = {}; setKeyVal(v,res[k]) } 
      else                          { res[k] = getRefVal(v,oData) }
    }
  }
  return ret
}

const objToTransform= { a: 'aValue', b: { c: 'cValue', d: 'dValue' } }
  ,   filteringObj =  { field1: 'a', field2: { subfield1: 'b.c', subfield2: 'b.d' } };

// test 
const filteredObj = myFunc(objToTransform, filteringObj);
// proof
console.log( filteredObj )
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash allows you to use the dot notation very easily.
Here is exactly what you want (<10 lines) :

```js
import _ from "lodash";

const objToTransform = {
    a: "aValue",
    b: {
        c: "cValue",
        d: "dValue"
    }
};

const filteringObj = {
    field1: "a",
    field2: {
        subfield1: "b.c",
        subfield2: "b.d"
    }
};

const filter = (model, data, filtered = {}) => {
    for (const field in model) {
        filtered[field] =
            typeof model[field] === "object"
                ? filter(model[field], data, model[field])
                : _.get(objToTransform, model[field]);
    }
    return filtered;
};

console.log(filter(filteringObj, objToTransform))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using (or interested in using) [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) (disclaimer: I'm one if its primary authors), this might work for you.  Ramda does not have a `deepMap` function, but it's easy to write one.  And using that, your transformation function is a one-liner:

```js
const deepMap = (fn) => (obj) => 
  is (Object, obj) ? map (deepMap (fn)) (obj) : fn (obj)

const transform = compose(applySpec, deepMap (compose (path, split('.'))))

const objToTransform = {a: "aValue", b: {c: "cValue", d: "dValue"}}
const filteringObj = {field1: "a", field2: {subfield1: "b.c", subfield2: "b.d"}}

console .log (transform (filteringObj) (objToTransform))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {is, map, compose, applySpec, path, split } = R       </script>
```

The key point here is [`applySpec`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec), which you could use directly with a slightly different format of `filteringObj`.  This would yield your desired results:

```
applySpec ({
  field1: path (["a"]), 
  field2: {
    subfield1: path (["b", "c"]), 
    subfield2: path (["b", "d"])
  }
}) (objToTransform)
```

The remainder of the `transform` function is simply to convert the `filteringObj` into that form above.

If you want to keep calling it as asked in the question, that is as `transform (objToTransform, filteringObj)` rather than `trasform (filteringObj) (objToTransform)`, it's only slightly more complex:

```js
const transform = (objToTransform, filteringObj) => 
  applySpec(deepMap (compose (path, split('.'))) (filteringObj)) (objToTransform)
```

You can write your own versions of those Ramda functions, it's [mostly easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55643020).  But a version of `applySpec` which works on nested properties would be a bit more difficult.