# Get a user by username?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to get a user by the username. I know how that works:

```
let user = client.users.find(user => user.username == "TESTname");
```

But what if there are 2 users who have the same username?

Comment: If there are multiple matches and you want them all, then use `.filter` instead of `.find`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all objects with matching Ids javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863855/find-all-objects-with-matching-ids-javascript)

Comment: Thanks! I think it's better to use the discord tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although getting a user with username instead of with id is a terrible idea, here is how you can do it with V13 :

```js
const users = client.users.cache.filter(user => user.username == "TESTname");
```

consider it is preferable to have the ID of the user, so you can fetch it directly from Discord:

```js
client.users.fetch("304541381798658048").then(user => {
console.log(user)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can get the user by the tag?

Comment: almost the same than the first answer, but replacing username by tag: `const users = client.users.cache.filter(user => user.tag == "koro#3351");`

Comment: np, happy coding!